# how to use SetMaxVideoDuration to record a video

Tags: android

how to use `setmaxvideoDuration` to record a video using camera-kit sdk?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the duration limit code below.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", maxDurationMiliSecond);
startActivityForResult(intent, ActivityRequests.REQUEST_TAKE_VIDEO);
```